# Scrape JSON response with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm new to Selenium and am struggling to extract data from JSON. I have tried multiple tools and haven't succeeded and coincidentally found that it seems like I could access the data through an API but it is split over thousands and thousands of pages.

I want to make the following actions automatically:

- Extract "title" or "slug", "reviews", "star_rating", "listing_price", "pretty_price"
- Extract "next_is_after" and concatenate it with "https://api.takealot.com/rest/v-1-10-0/searches/products,filters,facets,sort_options,breadcrumbs,slots_audience,context,seo?" load it and start the extraction from the beginning. This could happen a couple 100k times judging by the summary in the above.

I would really appreciate any pointers into the right direction. I am already failing at extracting the data. So if you could point me in the right direction with the below it would already be a lot of help.

```html
import requests
res = requests.get('https://api.takealot.com/rest/v-1-10-0/searches/products,filters,facets,sort_options,breadcrumbs,slots_audience,context,seo?').json()

for data in res:
    print(data["next_is_after"])
```

Comment: It would have been nice if you added a link to the API documentation. This is a very complex JSON response. You need to understand the structure of the JSON file. I recommend making several requests with each category from "section_keys" separately. This will allow you to deal with much smaller and simpler JSON structured responses.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a public documentation for this API, I only found it by coincidence when looking at Network>XHR in Chrome, so I don't even think the public is supposed to use it like I want to. I will play around with it some more and hopefully I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response json is an object of objects. So you need to fetch the data accordingly.

**Solution:**

```
import requests
res = requests.get('https://api.takealot.com/rest/v-1-10-0/searches/products,filters,facets,sort_options,breadcrumbs,slots_audience,context,seo?').json()

next_is_after = res['sections']['products']['paging']['next_is_after']

for data in res['sections']['products']['results']:
    name, slug, reviews, star_rating, listing_price, pretty_price = data['product_views']['core']['title'], data['product_views']['core']['slug'], data['product_views']['core']['reviews'], data['product_views']['core']['star_rating'], data['product_views']['buybox_summary']['listing_price'], data['product_views']['buybox_summary']['pretty_price']
    print(name, slug, reviews, star_rating, listing_price, pretty_price)

print("Next is after : ", next_is_after)
```